# SwitchCompat and supportLib version 25.3.0

Tags: android, android-support-library

Updating **com.android.support:appcompat-v7** lib from version 25.2.0 to 25.3.0 I noticed that the class `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat` has been annotated `@RequiresApi(14)
@TargetApi(14)`. This breaks my app, because I've been specifying `minSdkVersion 11` since long time ago.

Why does a v7 support lib class require Api14 ?

Comment: An issue has been filed, but no response yet: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=251302.

Comment: Not sure if you've been following that issue, but I just today saw that this has been fixed in 25.3.1, apparently.